# I am unable to generate (or print) the data retrieved from the data base in PDF using JSPDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server

i am new to **Javascript** and i am unable to print the data which is retrived from the **database**.
Here the concept is when i upload a file, i should get the data to be displayed in the browser and i want to **print the retrieved data in PDF**. i could able to retrieve that data when i am generating with **.xlxs** format but for **PDF format i couldnt**.

```css
html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #mainWindow {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;

        }

        .width-100 {
            width: 100% !important;
        }

        #map {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            height: calc(100% - 90px);
            width: 100%;
            border-top: 1px solid grey;
        }

        html,
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .disp-inline {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 5px;
        }

        .dijitBorderContainer-child {
            left: 0 !important;
        }

        .dojoxGrid {
            width: 100% !important;
        }

        /* (A) FULL SCREEN WRAPPER */
        #spinner {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 9999;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            transition: opacity 0.2s;
        }

        /* (B) CENTER LOADING SPINNER */
        #spinner img {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%);
        }

        /* (C) SHOW & HIDE */
        #spinner {
            visibility: hidden;
            opacity: 0;
        }

        #spinner.show {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
        }

        .dojoxGridArrowButtonChar {
            display: inline-block !important;
        }

        .dojoxGridColCaption {
            display: inline-block;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>DATA VALIDATION</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.39/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.39/esri/css/esri.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.39/"></script>

    <!-- <script src="jspdf.debug.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

   
</head>

<body class="tundra">
    <div id="mainWindow" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer"
        data-dojo-props="design:'headline', gutters:'false'">
        <div class="width-100" id="header" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top'"
            style="height:58px;text-align:left;font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;color:#400D12; height: 95px;">
            <div class="row" style="margin: 0;">
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <img src="logo.png" style="width: 250px; margin: 4px;" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-11" style="text-align: center;">
                    <h3>DMT DATA VALIDATION</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="width-100" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'">
            <div id="spinner">
                <img src="loader.gif" style="height: 50px;" />
            </div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" style="height: 80px;">
                <div class="row" style="margin: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid grey;">
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <div class="disp-inline">
                            <label style="display: inline-block;margin-left: 5px;" for="selectTemplate">Select
                                Template</label>
                            <select id="selectTemplate"
                                style="width: 325px; padding: 5px; margin: 5px; display: inline-block;">
                                <option value="AddressingData">Addressing Data</option>
                                <option value="HardLandscaping">Hard Landscaping</option>
                                <option value="IrrigationFacilities">Irrigation Facilities</option>
                                <option value="ParkingFacilities">Parking Facilities</option>
                                <option value="PedestrianAndCycling">Pedestrian And Cycling</option>
                                <option value="PublicTransportFacilities">Public Transport Facilities</option>
                                <option value="RoadAuxiliaryFeatures">Road Auxiliary Features</option>
                                <option value="RoadNavigation">Road Navigation</option>
                                <option value="RoadStructuresAndFurniture">Road Structures And Furniture</option>
                                <option value="SignsAndSignPoles">Signs And Sign Poles</option>
                                <option value="SoftLandscaping">Soft Landscaping</option>
                                <option value="StormwaterFacilities">Storm water Facilities</option>
                                <option value="StreetlightingFacilities">Street lighting Facilities</option>
                                <option value="StreetlightingPowerAndControlSystem">Street lighting Power And Control
                                    System
                                </option>
                                <option value="TrafficControl">Traffic Control</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <div class="disp-inline" style="margin-top: 14px;">
                            <form encType="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="gdbzipUploadForm">
                                <div className="field">
                                    <label style="display: inline-block;" className="file-upload" title="Upload ZIP"
                                        for='UploadzipFile'>Upload GDB
                                    </label>
                                    <input style="display: inline-block;width: 325px;" type="file" name="file"
                                        id="UploadzipFile" accept='.zip' />
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <!-- <div>
                                <label style="display: inline-block;" className="file-upload" title="Upload ZIP"
                                    for='UploadzipFile'>  Html to PDF  
                                </label>
                                <button onclick="javascript:createPdf()" id="cmd">Generate PDF</button>
                            </div> -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 14px;">
                            <a style="cursor: pointer; display: none;" href="#" id="downloadreflink">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></i>
                                Download Report
                            </a>                            
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 14px;">
                            <a onclick="javascript:createPdf()" style="cursor: pointer; display: none;" href="#" id="generatePdf">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></i>
                                Generate PDF Report
                            </a>                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="gridDiv" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="width-100" id="bottomdiv" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
            data-dojo-props="region:'bottom'" style="height: 50px;">
            <label id="errorlabel" style="display: none; color: red;"></label>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Here when i upload the .zip file I will get the data in the broswer. and i want to generate that in PDF?? how to do that